# error in database when the program is run but compiles perfectly

Tags: java, database, fxml

It's called Exception in Application start method

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

I've already done some research including the change the "location" solution and yet I still don't know my error is?

```java
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/databasefinalproject/FXMLDocument(1).fxml"));

       Scene scene = new Scene(root);

       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
   }
```

I've already connected it to the database and compiled it but it compiles perfectly the only problem is when I started to run it it display the error-

Exception in Application start method

```java
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line is throwing the Exception?